# How to deserialize application/json+hal messages with feign client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to deserialize my application/json+hal message from my db-service, which was produced by Spring.io jpa-data-rest module, but I am not able to deserialize the message as java models on my business logic service.

I tried to update my project according to the following tutorial: https://reflectoring.io/accessing-spring-data-rest-with-feign/.

If I access the rest resource with the feign client by returning string at the end, it succsessfully returning the string response of my db-service. If I returning the response as Resources, I receive an empty java object.

As a test I also used my jpa entity classes from my db-service as a deserialization template class, which returns also a empty java object.

The model used for deserialization:

```java
public abstract class AbstractNationModelBase implements Serializable {

    private String uuid;

    public AbstractNationModelBase(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }


    public AbstractNationModelBase() {
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

[...]
}
```

```
public class UserModel extends AbstractNationModelBase implements Serializable {


    private String username;

    private String password;

    private boolean isAdmin;


    public UserModel(String uuid, String username, String password, boolean isAdmin) {
        super(uuid);
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public UserModel(String username, String password, boolean isAdmin) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public UserModel(){
        super();
    }
```

```
@FeignClient(value="nation-database-service")
public interface UserFeignProxy {



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value="/users")
    Resources<UserModel> GetAllUsersByModel();
}
```

The correct response text:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "uuid": "815b53b0-cd33-4813-bce3-a7c4989b0b10",
                "username": "Testiman",
                "password": "peter_test",
                "admin": true,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/1"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/profile/users"
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/search"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

The result should be to deserialize it into my model class. I would appreciate it if somebody can share some experiance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after checking the following github issue:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/127

I added a custom  AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter as mentioned in the issue